# VANET Simulation using SUMO

Tags: veins, sumo, plexe

I am trying to use SUMO in my MATLAB VANET simulator, and as per my understanding, SUMO is a standalone mobility simulator which can simulate different mobility models such as: car following (platoon), lane changing and traffic intersections.
On the other side, the VANETs applications shall make use of the VANETs protocol messages (Beacon messages or EMG or whatever) and take actions based on these infos and update the vehicles' mobility as well.

I am already familiar with veins and plexe frameworks which already make use of SUMO via TraCI, however I can't understand the big picture for how they affect mobility in SUMO!
For instance, in Plexe framework, sumo configuration files with vehicle routings can be loaded in SUMO and simulate the platoon scenario itself, so what is the value added from using VANETs protocol messages?
The same for lane changing simulation, SUMO will perform lane change for vehicles based on certain  conditions, so what have the VANET simulator to add using the VANETs protocol messages?

Answer (score 1):

> in Plexe framework, sumo configuration files with vehicle routings can
> be loaded in SUMO and simulate the platoon scenario itself, so what is
> the value added from using VANETs protocol messages?

Cooperative Adaptive Cruise Control (CACC) requires information about what the preceding vehicle **plans** to do (as opposed to simply observing what the preceding vehicle is doing). This is only possible if the preceding vehicle communicates its plans wirelessly. Plexe makes it possible to simulate the fact that this wireless exchange of information...

- takes some time and causes some load on the channel which, in turn, depends on the amount of information exchanged by other vehicles
- can lose information if...

  - vehicles are too far away
  - vehicles are (partially) hidden behind obstacles
  - vehicles receive multiple transmissions simultaneously
- (any many more effects)

All of this is simulated by a wireless network simulation made possible by the simulation models of Plexe and Veins running in OMNeT++.

Comment: Thnaks Dr Sommer for your clarification, one more question regarding SUMO configurations file, are there specific configurations (or actions) need to be done to avoid undesired SUMO actions?
For example, If I force a collision by setting a vehicle's speed to zero, the following vehicles may change lane itself and this action is needed to be done through TraCI not by SUMO itself.

Comment: SUMO was, for the most part, designed to simulate normal traffic, not abnormal states like traffic signal violations or collisions, so any simulation where you try to provoke such things will need to be tightly controlled by you, e.g., via TraCI calls (like you said, forcing the speed of a vehicle to zero, forcing another vehicle to not switch lanes, etc etc)